# How do I get the contents of list sent into a procedure in Tcl?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a TCL procedure that makes a function call to a loaded package that returns a list. When I query the list with llindex for the number of entries, it is accurate. But, when I send that list to a procedure that populates a Tk Listbox, the list has no entries; the llindex function states the number of entires in the list is zero. For a piece of code, in my main code there is:

```
set ents [pw::Grid getAll -type pw::Connector]
makeWindow . $ents
```

The $ents has 17 elements in it. Then in my **makeWindow** procedure, I have:

```
makeWindow {root args} {
    label $base.targetDeltaTxt -text "Target Cell:"
    entry $base.targetDelta -cursor {} -textvariable entry
    ...
    set num_cons [expr ([llength $args]-1)]
    ...
}
```

The $num_cons is 1, though when it was sent it has 17. It seems that in TCL, sending a list to a procedure concatenates all list elements into a single line of text. Why?

Comment: I think you're going to have to post some of the code for us to see the issue.

Comment: from the wording of the question  I have the impression, that you use the lindex command, where llength would be appropriate. lindex returns values from a list, llength returns the length a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into the fact that having the last parameter of a proc named "args" causes special behaviour.  See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm for the details.  Renaming the parameter from `args` to anything else, e.g. `ents` should fix the problem.

Comment: The link doesn't work. But the changing of **args** to **connectors** made the procedure work as expected. Odd that _args_ is some keyword.

Comment: @StephenAlter `args` can be pretty useful. In your specific case, you can use `[llength [lindex $args 0]]` if you want to keep the name `args`, because it is a list containing all additional arguments passed to the procedure. Also the link works.

Comment: An alternative form of the documentation link is https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm , also another page that may help to explain is http://wiki.tcl.tk/1627